# Why does this Javascript function using new Date() only runs once?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function which returns a date string, it runs once, then after that I get errors saying "...clientTime() is not a function..." I tried to set the date back to nothing if it exists already. I'm not sure what to do.

Sorry I didn't show it here but the variables are declared externally as global variables.

```
function clientTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        dd    = now.getDate();
        MM    = now.getMonth()+1;
        if(MM < 10) {
        MM = '0'+MM.toString();
        }
        yyyy  = now.getFullYear();
        hh    = now.getHours();
        mm    = now.getMinutes();
        if(mm < 10) {
            mm = '0'+mm.toString(); 
        }
        ampm  = "";
        // determine if it's currently am or pm
        if(hh < 12) {
        hh = '0'+hh.toString();
        ampm = "AM";
        }else if(hh > 12) {
        ampm = "PM";
        }
        // modify hours change from 24 to 12 format
        switch (hh) {
        case (12):
            hh = 00;
        case (13):
            hh = 01;
        case (14):
            hh = 02;
        case (15):
            hh = 03;  
        case (16):
            hh = 04;
        case (17):
            hh = 05;
        case (18):
            hh = 06;
        case (19):
            hh = 07;
        case (20):
            hh = 08;
        case (21):
            hh = 09;
        case (22):
            hh = 10;
        case (23):
            hh = 11;
        }   
        return(MM+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy+' '+hh+':'+mm+' '+ampm);
    }

function alertClientTime() {
    alert(clientTime());
}

alertClientTime();
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/zvewca11/). Somewhere in code you haven't shown, you must have `clientTime = ...` -- e.g., you're overwriting the function reference with something else.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works more than once for you?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it invalid if I want the returned value of that function to say clientTime = clientTime( ); ?

Comment: @joehungjohn Why it should run more than once? You have no loop or timeout...

Comment: It's not *invalid*, but that overwrites the function reference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah that seems to have been the problem, thanks

Comment: @Justinas I didn't intend for it to run more than once, other than if the form that it's associated with is re-submitted again where the current time would have to be calculated again. But I was using the same name for the function as the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it invalid if I want the returned value of that function to say clientTime = clientTime( );

It's not *invalid*, but it overwrites the function reference with the result, which means on the next pass it's not a function anymore and you get the error you described. So just use a different name for the variable you're assigning to:

```
var theTime = clientTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work as expected.

Quick tip btw:
 `hh % 12` (Remainder operator)
produces the same result as your entire switch case :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably are overwriting your function somewhere on your code, check if the function name is duplicated or it's called somewhere else. If I take this piece of code works as intended. Also you can shorten the code but @Chris Nordqvist said that before me

**EDIT:** if are using dates a lot I recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/),  it's super useful

Comment: other people have suggested that as well, thanks for mentioning it

Comment: You should go take a look at moment.js, could save you a lot of time

Comment: right the funny thing is I may not need the client's time... I'm dealing with time zones and sending/receiving orders or maybe that is exactly what moment.js is for ha :)